# Should developer tools, languages, frameworks, etc. be standardized across an organization?

Tags: standardized

The organization that I currently work for seems to be heading in the direction of dictating to software developers which tools, languages, frameworks, etc. must be used. However, nobody has convinced me that this is a good thing. The main argument I have heard is that it will make training easier. But, after developing software for over 10 years, I've never relied on training to learn how to use an IDE, programming language, or anything else; so I just can't relate.

With the rapid speed at which technology evolves, and the s-l-o-w-n-e-s-s at which I know the standards will adapt, I am concerned that my customers will have requirements that I won't be able to easily implement or won't be able to implement as efficiently as I should. For example, if there is a UI requirement for an auto-complete feature in a web app, and no API has been approved for this yet, I would need to implement auto-complete myself as opposed to using one of the many APIs that provide it out of the box.

A more radical example is if my customers wanted to have Google Wave features. In that case I would want the flexibility of configuring my development environment (including the IDE) and selecting appropriate frameworks (ex: GWT) to use.

Please provide feedback on whether or not you think that software developer tools, languages, etc should be standardized and a few points to support your argument.

Comment: Also, please make this a community wiki.  It's seems more like a discussion topic.  It's also feels subjective.

Comment: I was tempted to edit my question since it gives the impression that I just blindly follow what's new and fashionable, but I chose to leave it as-is so the replies would make sense. But, just to clarify, I'm not 100% against standardization. What I am against is 100% standardization.

Answer (score 11):

There is a lot of benefit for standardization.  My organization has fairly set standards on what technology we will use.  We realize strong benefits in the following areas ...

1. Hiring.  It is easy to describe what technologies we are looking for and make sure our recruiters are looking for the right people.
2. License/Software costs.  I can buy enterprise licenses easily.  It gives me the opportunity to keep costs down by letting me spend more with a smaller number of vendors and thus get more leverage.
3. Consistency of delivery.  Our teams have a very good idea of what projects will take to build, rollout and maintain because they have done it with success before (and they know the pitfalls too).

   - Agility.  I can have one team take over for another or one individual take over for another more easily because of standardization.
   - Quality.  We have peer reviews across teams as well as QA across teams.

Without a consistent use of a technology stack, tools, languages and frameworks, these types of benefits would be more difficult to realize.  I am not closed off to new technologies, but there has to be a concrete reason beyond "what if I want to ..."

Comment: Couldn't have said it better.

Comment: I definitely agree with standardization on tool chain for all the above reasons and would add deployment and troubleshooting to the benefits. As the organization size grows the arbitrary introduction of new dependencies and testing requirements can have negative impacts.

However I do consider it beneficial to encourage a level of growth and examination of additional tools and items. Generally this is done in the form of internal projects and efforts that do not have the same deployment and testing demands.

Comment: +1 Couldn't have said it better either - as you can see from my answer below...

Answer (score 2):

You have a mixed bag here.

I wouldn't standardize on IDEs, because every developer works differently.  Those who are insanely proficient in emacs may see their performance suffer if forced to use Visual Studio.  I optimize my Visual Studio experience with a 30" monitor and find it incredibly productive.

However, standardizing on some tools, such as SCons or make or something to build products is perfectly reasonable.

Banning some libraries and having a process where new libraries are either approved or not is also very reasonable.  I know lots of companies that ban boost, or JQuery, or ban open source libraries in general, etc.  And they had good reasons for doing it.  I know I got fairly upset when an intern incorporated some random "security" library he found on the internet without running it by anyone.

In the end every company is different.  You have to be standardized enough to avoid serious complications and issues as people come and go, or as new products are formed and organizational structures change.  But you have to be flexible enough to avoid re-inventing every wheel you need.

The important thing is to have clear reasons for adopting a certain tool or banning some other tool or library.  You can't just have management dictate that thou shalt use this and not that without consulting the engineering team and making the decision for good reasons.  And once decisions are made those reasons should be written down and clearly communicated.

And also, if, in the end, your favorite tool or library isn't adopted, please don't whine about it.   Be adaptable and do your job, or find a new one that makes you happier.

Answer (score 2):

I once worked for a manager who felt the need to innovate at *every* level of his software development operation.  Every development tool had to be cutting edge (preferably in beta).  Many of the tools he asked us to use didn't have good documentation, and training was not available.  Ultimately, most of the technology we tried simply *didn't work*.  We wasted a lot of time churning through new technologies, only to dump them when it became clear we couldn't make progress.

I tried to make the case that innovation is perfect in the area where your [value proposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_value_proposition) lies.  Innovation can also be used judiciously where standard techniques fail.  But for most mundane tasks, using tried-and-true tools and methods should be the default.  Less risk, less cost, less management attention needed.  So you can focus time and energy on the areas where innovation has the most benefit.

So I think standardization has an important role.  But blindly saying everything must be standard is just as sure to fail as my manager who thought everything must be innovative.

Comment: +1: crazy levels innovation are a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

One unpleasant consequence of standardization is that it tends to stifle innovation.

Innovation is scary.  It involves cost and risk.

Standardization is not scary.  It reduces cost and risk in the short term.  Until your competitors have created a game-changing innovation.  Then standardization is very costly.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just disagree and think that this is a false dichotomy for the reasons given in my answer.

Comment: I totally disagree. Standardization doesn't have to stifle inovation. Standardization increase productivity of a team. Imagine having to work on a program written by a teammate in different language just because he felt like trying something different. You seem to advocate just doing whatever you feel like in the name of inovation. Obviously this would not work in a team oriented environment. Standardization is good, but standard have to be reviewed on a regular basis to make sure they are still relevant.

Comment: While standardization can "hinder" options, at the same time it sets a foundation and narrows the focus on solving the problem. If you, say, standardize on .NET, you implicitly narrow your potential solution space. At the same time, having fewer choices can improve decision making and response time with less options to consider. Finally, much creativity has been employed working "within standards".

Answer (score 1):

The number one argument in favor of standardization is that it maximizes the ability of the organization as a whole to use a common body of knowledge.  Don't know how custom web controls are built in ASP.NET/C#?  Ask Bill down the hall who has the knowledge.  If you use different tools, such organizational wisdom is cut off at the knees.  While it is *not* good to be restricted to a least common denominator (and hopefully your management will realize this) you should not overlook the benefits of shared experience!

UPDATE: I do *not* agree that innovation and standardization are polar opposites. Indeed, would we have nearly the level of web innovation if we still had the mishmash of networking standards characteristic of the 1980s?  No we would not.  Of course, we might have more innovation on new low-level networking protocols but is that really worth it?  In its place, we've had an explosion of creativity within the bounds of TCP/IP and the Web standards (http, html, etc.)

The trick is knowing how to standardize without using it as an argument for closing down all new exploration.  For example, we use only ASP.NET/C#/SQL Server in my company but I'm perfectly open to the use of new tools within this framework (we recently adopted the DevExpress reporting package, for example, supplanting the earlier standard).

Answer (score 1):

Whether you develop operations software for internal clients, or products for external clients, there is no compelling reason *not* to standardize. You certainly did not give one.
Had you seen how companies are struggling with holding heterogenous products together that have been maintained for 10 years or more, and are now a conglomerate of various technologies that developers at some point thought made sense, you would not have asked this question.

From the top of my head, I could name at least 2 well-known software companies that will be driven out of business because their cost of maintenance has become so high that they can no longer compete (but I won't).

I think the misconception here is that suppressing individualism would supress innovation. That is simply not true. It is poor technical leadership that suppresses innovation.

Answer (score 1):

A major issue with standardization is that once standards are out there, they get stamped in concrete and are difficult to change. This is why our corporate IT environment is stuck on IE 6, and the best change control system we have access to is CVS. Given this situation, some developers break the rules, and some find jobs at more innovative companies.

Comment: But this is not the problem of the standard it is the problem of the company, leadership to change this standards and review them on a regular basis

Comment: +1: Standards are very sticky.  Reviewing a standard doesn't do much.  Once it's in place, it has history; any change can be stated as "risky" and "disruptive".

Answer (score 1):

Standardization is a must for a productive development team. However that doesn't mean that you can't revist the standards from time to time to adjust them to new technologies and trends.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the organization I think.  One like Microsoft, yes, there should be a bit of a standard.  A small business with one IT department, no.  A larger business with several offices around the world ... maybe.

it all depends :-P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the organization has a broad suite of enterprise applications to manage, I'd say no for the following reasons, though I may be taking the message of *everything being the same* a bit too literally:

- Compromise on using best-of-breed for systems, e.g. if all the databases are to be MS-SQL then any Oracle DB solution is thrown out.  This would also apply to the fact that everyone using an IDE has to use the same one whether they be doing Data Warehouse report development, web applications, console applications or winForms.  I'm thinking of systems like ERP, CRM, SCM, CMS, SSO and various other TLAs, FLAs, and SLAs. (LA = Letter acronyms for a decoding hint if you need it)
- Upgrading by committee is another interesting issue.  Where if each team can choose their tools and have one person that decides it is to upgrade things, e.g. start using Visual Studio 2008 instead of Visual Studio 2005,  now have to determine at what threshold is it worth it to upgrade everyone simultaneously which may be a big headache if there are more than a few developers.  For example, over the past 10 years when would there be IDE changes, framework changes, etc.?
- Exceptions to the standards.  Could a contractor bring in something not used in the organization if they believe it helps them build better software, e.g. Resharper or other add-ons that some contractors believe are very worthwhile that the organization doesn't want to spend the money to get?  What about legacy systems that may make the standard become a bit unwieldy, e.g. this was built in ASP.Net 1.1 and so everyone has to have VS 2003 installed even if most will never use it?

Just my thoughts on this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several good reasons to standardize.

First, it allows the enterprise better organizational flexibility, if everybody is more or less familiar with the same things.  It also allows people to help each other better.  I can't help with problems in the ASP.NET stuff, and there's not all that many people who can help me on the C++ side.

Second, it reduces support problems and expenses.  Oracle and SQL Server are both decent products, but using both for similar functions is only going to cause problems.  Not to mention that I've been in shops using several widely different platforms to do similar things, and it wasn't fun.

Third, there are some things that just have to be standardized.  We couldn't operate half with VS 2005 and VS 2008, since we keep project files under source control.  We had to pick a time and convert over.

Fourth, in some businesses, it simplifies the regulatory problems.  I don't know what business you're in.  I work at a place where we can get away with making mistakes right now, but I've also contracted at a bank and a utility, where it's necessary to be able to show auditors that everything is going in a standard way.

Fifth, it can simplify procurement, if you're dealing with software that costs money.

This doesn't particularly limit us, since if there's something we need that isn't standardized on we just go ahead and get it or do it.

If you want to make a business case against standardization, you'll need to have a business-related argument.  Your argument seems to be that you won't be able to implement features the user wants, and that is a consideration.  Got another argument?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with standardizing on an IDE that is rich enough to be configured for individual developers.

However, do make sure that you don't prevent individual developers from using additional tools, as long as the tools are licensed and that the use of the tool by one developer doesn't require all other developers to use it.

For instance, I happen to use [NORMA](http://www.ormfoundation.org/files/folders/norma_the_software/default.aspx) to help me design databases. The output is SQL Server DDL (or anything else I want). I can make the DDL part of the project without making my NORMA source part of it. Later developers do not need to use NORMA to work on the project.

On the other hand, if I decided to use the [Configuration Section Designer](http://codeplex.com/csd/) to create configuration sections, then future developers would also have to use it. A decision would need to be made about whether to use that tool.

Answer (score 0):

The company I work for uses C#, ASP.NET, JavaScript and generates HTML.  The advantages over and above those mentioned above are that there is a perception of improved velocity for maintenance and adaptive changes.  The disadvantages include generating some boredom for people who are technically savvy (geeky) and prefer to use a mix and match of languages, depending on what they fancy is better suited, or for 'performance reasons'.

Technical and personal supervision is always good to have when you are developing as fast as you can to meet tight deadlines and competing in a highly saturated market for web development.